# zend studio 5.5.1 on windows xp - won't open!

Tags: zend-studio

I have been using zend studio 5.5.1 for the last year and and a half (on windows xp), with some occasional issues, such as a blank error dialog box when I started the program, but always went away when i restarted my computer, and usually got messages about javaw.exe errors.

But now, the program does not open at all. What happens is, I get a little dialog that says Loading project - this is normal... but then, nothing. The zend program item is sitting in the taskbar, but when i click on it - nothing! there is nothing to show. i can right click and press close, but that is all.

restarting computer did not help. i just uninstalled it, downloaded again from zend website, and reinstalled. tried opening - get loading box, seems to have loaded, even got tip of the day box. but there is nothing showing behind them. once i closed the tip box, i dont have any indication that zend is open besides the program item in the taskbar. windows task manager says it is running...

anyone have a clue? help!!! thanks

UPDATE:
I found [this blog post](http://www.thelinuxblog.com/zend-studio-wont-start-fix/) with a fix for Linux... I am a windows user and that is greek to me, anyone who can translate for me what I can do for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow, did a google search for the equivalent of rm -r ZDE as suggested in the link above, and then I typed the following in the cmd prompt: rmdir /s ZDE
voila! it works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Running Zend Studio 5.5.1 on Windows 7:

- Right click Zend-icon for Windows 7 program properties
- On Compatibility tab set modus to Windows Vista and apply

Enjoy!